# Entity Frame Navigation property for table joins

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 3 tables namely Ship[ShipID, Name, YearOfConstr, CompanyID(FK), TypeID(FK)] which is a bridge between Company[CompanyID, Name, Headquarter] and Type[TypeID, Description, NoPassengers]

I wanted to query the names of all Company which has a specific type = "xxx" and whose headquater = "yyy"

Below is what I have tried, but it's returning nothing and won't throw an error either.

```
public List<string> AllShippingCompanies(string TypeDescription, string headquarters)
{

    var list = from shipcomany in dbContext.Ships.Where(x => x.Type.Description == TypeDescription && x.ShippingCompany.Headquarter == headquarters)
               select shipcomany.ShippingCompany.Name;


    return list.ToList();
}
```

What could I have been doing wrong ?

Comment: Looks like fine for me, are you sure there's a Ship that matches theses parameters? Be aware that you are using "==" it means that it must be equal, case differences may not return true depending on DB's Collation. Try to use `Contains()` to see if something match.

Comment: You have a mix of syntax in there which is possibly confusing, but other than that I see nothing incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just check and found there are no related data in my DB. The code works fine. It's correct. Thanks for your time